# .html page not loading PHP sessions

Tags: php, html, session

I'm using custombuild 2.0 by directadmin, with php-fpm version 5.6 and mod_php version 5.5 installed.

No problems running php with 5.5, but switching over to php-fpm 5.6, I have a problem with sessions on html pages.

Figured out there's no problem with session_start() or the use of addhandler htaccess in the htaccess. PHP code is running just fine in html pages.

Two identical pages, except for the file extension (.php and .html). The .php file works just fine with sessions. The .html file does not. It seems to run under apache user, while the php file runs under the current domain user. This is why the sessions are inaccessible due to wrong ownership of the directory/folder stated in session.save_path.

Printing php_ini_loaded_file() in the .html file shows: "/usr/local/lib/php".
Printing php_ini_loaded_file() in the .php file shows the correct php 5.6 php.ini that came with custombuild 2.0.

How is it possible that the wrong php.ini gets loaded, only in the html file? The two files (html and php) are exactly the same besides the file extension.

Your help is most welcome!

Comment: .html files don't process PHP unless you go out of your way to enable that. Did you do that?

Comment: you need to instruct your server to treat `.html` files as php.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not sure if that is a good idea...

Comment: @arkascha it's an option. That, or they'll need to rename them all to `.php` or use ajax maybe or an iframe.

Comment: What do you mean by "the current domain user"?

Comment: Yeah you can easily use htaccess to see html as php.

Comment: The server is instructed to treat .html files as php. No problem there. The problem is that the sessions don't work.

Comment: Maybe add a mod_rewrite inside your .htaccess file to make your .html file work as .php

Comment: And you don't think it makes sense to add to the question how you implemented the logic that takes care that requests to different host names are served by processes executed under different server side user accounts? Simply because that is highly unusual (though certainly possible), and has a lot of influence on how the http server is operating.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out the a workaround to my session problem.

I'm forcing php-fpm56 in the php-fpm56.conf to use the apache user, owner and group, like this:

```
user = apache
group = apache
listen.owner = apache
listen.group = apache
```

This way both html and php pages work with user apache, so there are no permission or owner problems.

This is by no way the way it is intended by php-fpm, but it will do for now.

Thanks all for your input.

Comment: Deleted some comments I made earlier because of possible sensitive info. They didn't contribute anyway.